# How does MetaMask save our mnemonic phrase? Is it safe enough?

Tags: security, metamask, javascript

How does MetaMask save our mnemonic phrase? Is it saved in browser local storage? Does it encrypt our mnemonic phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How MetaMask save our mnemonic phrase?

The mnemonic phrase saved in the `vault`.

`vault`-  is an encrypted storage.

> Does it save in browser local storage?

Yes, but the phrase is encrypted.

> Does it encrypt our mnemonic phrase?

There is a [`library`](https://github.com/MetaMask/vault-decryptor) which MetaMask uses to decrypt vault data.